# Icicles - not show all history commands

Tags: icicles, history-variables

Windows 10, Emacs 26.1, Icicles,

1. In *scratch* buffer I search text "buffer" by command "`I-Search`"
   [image]

2.Open test.txt and run command "`replace-string`"

[image]

3. Start `helm-occur` and set pattern `hello`
   [image]
4. Then I want to get ALL commands that I run in minibuffer.

So I use command "`icicle-insert-history-element`"

[image]

Here result:
[image]

But where commands "`I-Search`" and "`Replase-string`" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is s bit unclear to me.

[Multi-command](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multi-Commands) `icicle-insert-history-element` (bound to `M-o`) is for inserting previous inputs into the active minibuffer using completion, appending them individually to whatever is already in the minibuffer.

If you want to see all previous (i.e., history) inputs for a given minibuffer history (e.g., a command history) then you can use `M-h` or `M-<pause>` when the minibuffer is active.

See the [History Enhancements](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_History_Enhancements) section of the Icicles doc for info about minibuffer history enhancements (including `M-o`, `M-h`, and `M-<pause>`).

With respect to Isearch and string replacement: Isearch does not, in fact, use the minibuffer, so input you type to Isearch is not recorded in any minibuffer history. String replacement typically uses its own minibuffer history. If you try an additional string-replacement command then your previous replacement inputs are available in its history.

If you are looking for a history of commands you have used, then you want to use `M-x` again and access its history of minibuffer inputs. (But that won't give you commands that you invoked using keys.)